# Does COUNT(*) make things faster?

Tags: mysql

OK, let's assume I have a big table with a 1k+ records, and that I need to take three records from it. Now, let's assume there are no records that meet the conditions. By doing a COUNT(*) using the same conditions and then doing a SELECT if the count is greater than zero, am I making my queries faster by making sure there are records available before doing a SELECT, or is this just a waste of time?

Comment: How is running the same search twice going to be quicker?

Comment: always selecting only required column is good if all you want is count because less data it has to process. [select count(column1) from ttt]

Comment: I don't see how. It has to do the same work on the table as when you do an ordinary `SELECT`, and now you're running two queries instead of one.

Comment: If all you care about is the count, then using `SELECT COUNT(*)` is better than doing `SELECT *` followed by calling `mysqli_num_rows`, since the latter has to transfer all the data from the server to the client. But if you're going to do the real `SELECT` whenever the count is more than 0, then you haven't saved anything.

Comment: I don't see how it could possibly be faster to run the query twice. You could look at the execution plans for each query and run benchmarks if your really curious, but this sounds like a case of over/premature optimization

Comment: @Barmar There was not specific mention of PHP here, and even if so, most DB interaction libraries (including PHP's mysqli) would be able to work with the result set in a buffered manner such that the number of rows would be returned with the initial query without having to retrieve the full result set.

Comment: @MikeBrant That was just an example. The server doesn't know that the program is just going to ask for the row count, it's going to start sending the result set to the client. So it's going to waste bandwidth even if the application ignores the data.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I use a script called phpBB and it forces me to always do the count before the query, so I've got this myth in my head that doing a COUNT(*) before the query was always the right way. Glad to see it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a tiny table in the overall scheme of things.  You should just query for your filtered results directly, and if you need to do something different in your app when no results are returned, just do a check against the number of rows returned to skip trying to work with the result set.

There would never be a case where the `COUNT()` approach performs better, because it would be doing the same exact query logic you would do on a full select anyway.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I use a script called phpBB and it forces me to always do the count before the query, so I've got this myth in my head that doing a COUNT(*) before the query was always the right way. Glad to see it's not.